# Notifications patterns in WCF

Tags: android, ios, wpf, wcf, notifications

We are planning to develop a `client server application`. The server component shall be developed as REST based `WCF Services`. The server component needs to send some notification to clients... The clients can be any of the following

**1- WPF based windows apps**

**2-ASP.NET web application**

**3-Android or iOS apps**

What is the best way of sending notifications

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use SignalR

It was originally built for ASP.net:

http://signalr.net/

But now also Works for Andriod:

http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/03/06/android-java-developers-signalr-sdk/

There is also a possibility to use it With a WPF Client:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client